# Python: Changing one object's data changes the other

Tags: python

I apologize ahead of time if my explanation is not coherent enough. I am new to python and coding. I'm currently trying to create a Pokemon program that will allow 2 users to battle each other. `moveList` is a global list that contains all the possible moves in the game.
`x` - is a file the stores which indexes correspond to which pokemon's moves. `pokeData.loadMoves` loads a preexisting move array inside each pokemon with 4 `move` objects. When i first add Arcanine's 4 moves, it is fine. However when I add eevee's moves, it rewrites over Arcanine's moves. I've spent about 40 minutes already trying to remedy this to no avail.

separate objects:

```
P1 = None
P2 = None

loadGame()

P1 = inputPokemon('player1')
P2 = inputPokemon('player2')
```

function:

```
for x in file.readlines():
    x = x.split(' ')
    if(x[0].strip().lower() == string):

        i =int(x[1])-1
        j =int(x[2])-1
        k =int(x[3])-1
        l =int(x[4])-1

        if(second == True):
            print("Arcanine's moves before loading eevee")
            for x in range(4):
                print(P1.move[x].name)

        pokeData.loadMoves(moveList[i],moveList[j],moveList[k],moveList[l])
        print("Load %s's moves " %x)

        if(second == True):
            print("Arcanine's moves after loading eevee")
            for x in range(4):
                print(P1.move[x].name)
```

loadMoves:

```
move=['','','','']
def loadMoves(self, move1, move2, move3, move4):
    self.move[0] = move1
    self.move[1] = move2
    self.move[2] = move3
    self.move[3] = move4
```

Output:

```
player2, please choose your Pokemon: Eevee
Loading moves for eevee
Arcanine's moves before loading eevee
['takedown']
['growl']
['flamethrower']
['confuseray']
Load 3's moves 
Arcanine's moves after loading eevee
['watergun']
['doubleteam']
['shockwave']
['tackle']
```

Comment: The two variables are most likely referencing the same object

Comment: I already tried checking if(pokeDataArg is P1) for the second data input and returns false

Comment: What is pokeData and what is the `function` that you provided code for?

Comment: A bit offtopic but general advice: Name your variables something that makes it obvious what it is. So instead of x for the file you could name it like movesFile or something.

Comment: Also, do yourself a service and read about "Short, Self Contained, Correct Examples": http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: need to list all relevant code (what is `P1`? `PokeData`? `second`?)

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the class variable `move`. Setting up that list as a class variable means all instances will be pointing to the same list object. Consider the following:

```
>>> class T:
...    move = [] # move defined as class variable
...    def update(self, v):
...        self.move[0:] = v
...
>>> c = T()
>>> c.move
[]
>>> d = T()
>>> d.update([1,2,3])
>>> c.move
[1, 2, 3]  # updates in d are seen in c
>>> c.update([4,5,6])
>>> d.move
[4, 5, 6]  # updates in c are equally seen in d
```

---

You should consider setting up `move` on the instance of the class i.e. in the `__init__` of the class. So the list is bound to each instance and not to the class itself:

```
class T:
    def  __init__(self):
       self.move = ['','','','']
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the exact answer I needed. I skipped a lot of tutorials and went straight into project mode. So all class variables are static across classes?

Comment: @andrewnvu Sort of. So mutable objects being what they are may not behave as intended as in this case.